Alternative to a single high spec'd diode
My series blocking needs to pass 8 A and I am wondering if I can use 4 diodes (rated 2 A each) instead of 8 A.
We have a cost constraint, hence we are looking for an alternative to replace a high spec'd diode (8 A).
Below is the idea that I have in mind.

I appreciate any suggestions/lessons regarding this. Thanks!

I wonder what the volume of your product is. I have a sneaky feeling that the engineering time you spend asking that question, reading the answers, and pondering it, will cost more than the diodes will cost for the entire production run of the product. Are you making something that will sell in 10k+ quantities? Otherwise, “saving money” on the diode is actually wasting money for the business :)

You'd probably be better-off with a dual diode in a single package, with each individual diode in the package rated for 5 or 6A, than with 4 individual diodes. A pair of diodes on the same internal die will share current far better than individual diodes ever can.

If you really have 4 indepedent loads, each of which takes a max of 2A, then you don't have a problem.

Or you could look into an "ideal diode", which typically uses a MOSFET.

Remember to also consider the dissipated heat, which will be 4 watts or more. A MOSFET based "ideal diode" chip could be a better option.

@Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Thank you, i was exploring other alternatives.

@brhans I'll check that out thank you.

@jpa Will take that into consideration and I will check the "ideal diode" option which Attie and you suggested.

@Neil_UK yes, I do have 4 independent loads. that was why I thought about this configuration might work. My load has an auto-cutoff at 2.2A, maybe I could use a 3A schottky diode instead.

Single diodes in parallel will not share current perfectly.
They also won't share perfectly imperfectly, so we can conclude that the total current rating is somewhere between 2A and 8A.
How much inbetween, depends on manufacturing variance, temperature matching, tempco, and V(I) curve.
As a rough feel (but short of doing actual engineering; I have no datasheet to reference, anyway), I would probably expect more like 6-8 in parallel for the required rating here.
A single say DPAK diode is looking pretty attractive for that case.
Single loads with single diodes, are absolutely no problem; the currents are set independent of each diode.

Tim, thanks for the input.
If each of my diode had separate individual loads, do you think this configuration would work? 2.2A max load for each diode (so I'm thinking of setting a 3A schottky diode)

Independent loads are fine, they're just separate branches. To be clear, parallel diodes won't share perfectly.

And if they don't share perfectly, one will fail prematurely. When that happens the remainder will unzip fast: I've seen something similar in an early switchmode PSU.

If the blocking voltage is low enough to allow you to use Schottky diodes, use them. If you need higher blocking voltage, i.e. silicon diodes, you need to add resistors in each branch to avoid thermal runaway due to negative tempco on the forward voltage on Si diodes. Check the datasheet for exact values, but it will be in the range of 200 mV at max current.
EDIT: I misremembered. Loose Schottkys may also experience thermal runaway. Pre-packaged ones, for example two with common cathode in TO-220 are normally thermally bonded strong enough to not requiring series resistors. Sorry about that. Again, check the datasheet for max difference in Vf over temperature and apply series resistance accordingly if you absolutely can’t use a single one.
Best solution is to just buy a 8+ A capable diode in the first place. Plenty of them available in the market.

Our working voltage with tolerance is up to 28.8 (24V +20%). So I believe a 30V Schottky diode will be fine with regards to your answer.
Would it be alright to use the Schottky diodes without the series resistance in each branch?

@Kevin I would never design with that little margin. 40 V minimum. Yes, it's ok to use Schottky's without series diodes unless you have extreme temperature difference between them. Check the datasheet for them and calculate how well they will share current. It won't be 1/n in each, but close.

how do you figure schottky's are safe to parallel?  they still have negative Vf tempco, like a PN diode.

@rohmeooo Sorry about that. I’ve updated my answer.

Incidentally, schottky are available in most any voltage rating these days -- with, trench MOS improvements I believe, Si offers up to 200V rating (maybe even more), and SiC takes over in the 600V+ range. PN diodes are still being improved by increment, and can do surprisingly well in many applications; and they remain superior in terms of low leakage, surge ratings, or of course, cost per rating.

Diode current sharing can be bad. This can be mitigated by overframing. In other words, by using more than four 2 ampere diodes for your 8 ampere need.
Both normal Si diodes and Schottky diodes have a negative temperature coefficient which is not good for current sharing. A common heatsink with good thermal coupling will help sharing.
Real diodes have a semiconductor junction with its well documented voltage equations like Erbers/Moll in series with bulk resistance.
The voltage across the bulk resistance is more significant in power devices driven at or near thier maximum current rating. For example, the voltage drop across a rectifier diode in a car alternator will be around 1.1 volts at the alternator's nameplate rating, so it can be seen that extra power wasting series resistors may not be needed.
Fortunately this series bulk resistance has a positive temperature coefficient which could balance out the undesirable negative temperature cofficient. Look at the curves carefully and you may get away with this.
From experience, some of the new SiC Schottky diodes have a stable overall positive temperature coefficient at reasonable currents and shared well on the bench.

I understand that current sharing is not a good idea.
However, from my diagram, each of the diode actually has a separate individual load which will not draw current from the other diodes. In this configuration, will this work?

@Kevin . the individual loads on your diagram   for your application ensure that there will not be current share problems .


Alternative to a single high spec'd diode

It appears the goal of the circuit is to protect against reverse connection of a DC power supply. This makes the solution simpler than rectifying AC current would be.
A good alternative is the classic P-MOSFET circuit (schematic from this question):

For a more detailed explanation of the options, see Onsemi application note AND90146.
